# How to Statically Link to the CRT with GCC?

Tags: gcc, static, mingw, mingw-w64, crt

How could one link statically to the CRT on Windows / macOS and Linux using GCC?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the linker option `-static` as shown below.

```
edd@ron:/tmp$ cat helloworld.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello, world\n");
}
edd@ron:/tmp$ gcc -o helloworld.dyn helloworld.c
edd@ron:/tmp$ gcc -static -o helloworld.static helloworld.c
edd@ron:/tmp$ ls -l helloworld.*
-rw-r--r-- 1 edd edd     69 2009-08-18 07:09 helloworld.c
-rwxr-xr-x 1 edd edd   6667 2009-08-18 07:10 helloworld.dyn
-rwxr-xr-x 1 edd edd 576348 2009-08-18 07:10 helloworld.static
edd@ron:/tmp$ ./helloworld.dyn
Hello, world
edd@ron:/tmp$ ./helloworld.static
Hello, world
edd@ron:/tmp$ ldd helloworld.static
        not a dynamic executable
edd@ron:/tmp$ ldd helloworld.dyn
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb7efc000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 (0xb7d83000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7efd000)
edd@ron:/tmp$
```

Comment: Won't work for MinGW on Windows. AFAIK, there is no way to escape the dependancy on MSVCRT.DLL using MinGW, though I'd be happy to be proved wrong.

Comment: Ah, yes, that other OS. Well at least I got two out three covered.

Comment: I tried to link with an without `-static`, I use MinGW on Win7, and it produce 2 different files (the static one is 1.5 Mo larger). I'm not expert at all, but I think it works fine...